# What is a Rollercoaster™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

If a sentence conforms to a certain rule, I call it a  Rollercoaster™. Find the rule that decides whether a sentence is a Rollercoaster™ or not.

### Sentences that are rollercoasters:

- Why?
- Oh oh!
- Hey, appreciate earth enthusiastically, cheerful will it be.
- Just be you.
- Every important-looking forenoon runs on tea.
- Review new approaches, fresh interconnections; remember, open an eye.
- Learning lets us see.
- Respecting moral incontrovertible protocol, exit or queue.
- Extraterrestrial entities live on X.

### Sentences that are not rollercoasters:

- Really?
- Hey there!
- Look deep into nature, and it will help you understand everything better.
- Just do it.
- Rainy days should be spent at home, with a cup of tea.
- Review new perspectives, fresh interconnections; remember, open an eye.
- I stood happily, by the sea.
- Respecting moral incontrovertible protocol, queue or exit.
- Extraterrestrial entities live on Planet X.

### Hints:

> Rollercoasters have ups and downs, but they eventually stop, in one place.

> The last word of every rollercoaster has a peculiar characteristic.

**Bonus Puzzle:** Create a 10-word Rollercoaster™.

Comment: Should we consider punctuation?

Comment: @bobble Punctuation is redundant; it only holds value in that it denotes that a hyphenated word is a single word.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A rollercoaster sentence:

1.

> Has a final word which can be replaced with a phonetically identical letter (e.g. tea = T, or X which is already a letter)

2. 

> Has word lengths which follow the order of a chain in the Collatz conjecture after applying the first rule - that is, odd numbers are multiplied by 3 and incremented, and even numbers are divided by 2, until the chain reaches 1. For example: the third sentence given follows the chain 3, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1.

One solution for the bonus puzzle:

> "Professional groups can, apparently, speak incomprehensible charades, even to you." With word lengths of 12, 6, 3, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1 (where you = U.)

Comment: Yes, that's correct!

Comment: I gave a sentence for the bonus puzzle, which is admittedly incoherent, but not more so than some of the examples